# SQL aggregation with case statement and group by

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I'm trying to understand the problem with this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE liveIn.state
                 WHEN ("NY" OR "NJ") THEN "group1" 
                 WHEN ("NC" or "SC") THEN "group2"
             END) AS state_groups
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_guid, state
        FROM users
          WHERE country="US" AND country IS NOT NULL) AS liveIn
GROUP BY state_groups;
```

The error I get is: "Can't group on 'state_groups'"

I have other code that solve my problem which look like this (but I'm trying to understand the problem with the one above):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_guid),
       CASE
           WHEN (state="NY" OR state="NJ") THEN "group1" 
           WHEN (state="NC" OR state="SC") THEN "group2"
       END AS state_groups
FROM users
     WHERE country="US" AND country IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY state_groups;
```

my output should look like this:

[image]

TKS!

P.S.- this is part of coursera sql learning course, so I'm working on Jupyter.

Comment: Then add what the query should do, example data and expected output

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the error you get? Which DBMS are you using? Do you have a column called `NY` or `US` in your table? Because `"NY"` or `"US"` are column identifiers in SQL.

Comment: I assume that you would like to understand the sql that you posted above - is this the case?

Comment: A course teaching you that `"US"` is a valid string constant in SQL shouldn't be trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `case when` returns group values but they are not useful when wrapped in a `count`, as they will all contribute as 1 to it. Furthermore, you cannot group by the aggregate you want to calculate based on a group. Note that you only have 1 column in your first SQL. You should have 2: one identifying the group, and the other the count. You merged the two into one, and that does not make sense.

This would be a valid alternative:

```
SELECT   CASE state
             WHEN "NY" THEN "group1" 
             WHEN "NJ" THEN "group1" 
             WHEN "NC" THEN "group2"
             WHEN "SC" THEN "group2"
             ELSE           "others"
         END AS state_group,
         COUNT(DISTINCT user_guid) AS user_count
FROM     USERS
WHERE    country = "US" 
GROUP BY state_group
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f42d8/2)

Note that if you put an `or` in this variation of the `when` clause, the second term of that `or` will be evaluated separately, and make the condition true, so all values will then end up in *group1*.

You could use the other variant of the `case when` syntax, where you can use `or` or even better, `in`:

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN state IN ("NY", "NJ") THEN "group1" 
              WHEN state IN ("NC", "SC") THEN "group2"
              ELSE                            "others"
         END AS state_group,
         COUNT(DISTINCT user_guid) AS user_count
FROM     USERS
WHERE    country = "US" 
GROUP BY state_group
```

Note that in this syntax, there is nothing between the `case` and the first `when`.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. but I'm not so sure why you say that 'case when' are not useful when wraping in a count. when I'm running this query: 
select 
'COUNT(CASE WHEN country="US" THEN "group1" END) AS groups
FROM users; 
and this query:
SELECT COUNT(user_guid) FROM users 
WHERE country="US"; I'm getting the same results

Comment: Any value ("group1", "group2", ...) you count, counts as one. It does not make distinction between "group1" and "group2" that way (in your first SQL in the question). But more importantly, your first query syntax is turning in circles: you define the group as the count, but you want the count to happen per group. This is a paradox that cannot be solved, and is why you get an error message.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?

Comment: I'm sorry... you did answer my question! Tks!!